# How can I get the Feature vector value?

Tags: python, vector, feature-extraction, euclidean-distance, sift

I'm doing some project to detect images with a few descriptor and calculate its similarity measure. In this case, I'm using the euclidean distance and I didnt know how to retrieve the feature vector value to get it done. can some one give me idea on this? btw I'm using python. any help are much appreciated.here is my coding that ive done so far

```
       # -*- coding -*-
    """
    Created on Sat Jun 13 14:08:09 2020
    
    @author: MuzhaffarAhmad
    """
    
    import cv2 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    
    #read images
    img1 = cv2.imread('handbag.jpg')  
    img2 = cv2.imread('handbagsketch.png') 
    
    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    #descriptor
    descriptor = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    
    keypoints_1, descriptors_1 = descriptor.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
    keypoints_2, descriptors_2 = descriptor.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
    
    #feature matching
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2, crossCheck=True)
    
    matches = bf.match(descriptors_1,descriptors_2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key = lambda x:x.distance)
    
    
    
    #plot and write image
    img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1, keypoints_1, img2, keypoints_2, matches[:50], img1, flags=2)
    fname = 'SIFT.png' 
    cv2.imwrite(fname,img3)
    plt.imshow(img3),plt.show()
    
    
 # calculating euclidean distance between vectors
from math import sqrt
 
# calculate euclidean distance
def euclidean_distance(a, b):
    return sqrt(sum((e1-e2)**2 for e1, e2 in zip(a,b)))
 
# define data
row1 = [???]
row2 = [???]
# calculate distance
dist = euclidean_distance(row1, row2)
print(dist)
```

so i put the ??? sign at the row1/row2 column which is the value of feature vector from my project that i really dont know how to get.

Comment: Hello @Muzhaffar! Welcome to the SO community! Could you tell us what you've done so far? Sharing code often makes your question more likely to get answers.

Comment: Okay @Ralubrusto i will edit back and added the coding